# Undefined method model_name_url in if there's no show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I did a controller called `api` in which I have actions that return data. In the app I also have a `Car` model and a `cars` controller (with all the standard routes), but I want to move every URL that I use into the `api` controller and remove the URLs that I don't use from my app. In the case of the `cars` controller I only use the URLs in which the json of all the cars are returned or the json of a particular car is returned (i.e. something like `index` and `show`).

The problem I have is that when I use the `json.jbuilder` to render the list of cars I also want to print the URL of those resources (`show`), so for example if I have the endpoint `/api/cars.json` I use the following `json.jbuilder`.

**views/api/cars.json.jbuilder**

```
json.array!(@cars) do |car|
    json.extract! family_bond, :id, :name, :image, :description
    json.url car_url(car, format: :json)
end
```

But `car_url` throws an error if I delete `resource: car` from the routes file. This is obvious since `car_url`should return the `show` action URL of every car.

**So my question is the following**

If I create the action to show the details of a car in the api controller (for example, something like `/api/car.json?id=1`), how can I tell Rails to use this endpoint instead of the standard one (`show`) when I use the car_url` method?

Comment: Did you tried to filter only needed routes with except switch in routes.rb? Like 
resources :photos, except: :show   or to allow resources :photos, only: [:index, :show]   ?

Comment: @Nezir Yes, but as I explained, I would like to not use `resources :car` at all and only use actions from the `api` controller.

Comment: but then you can set single get route in routes.rb? for example get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show', as: 'patient'   or more about routes here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html  in general you must have route if you want to access some controller action

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to have the path and url helpers work without the route being specified in the routes, as when you use some other utility to route the URLs to the controllers.  However, if you get the routes.rb to specify how to route an URL to your API, it will work.

```
resource :car, controller: 'api'
```